# How can I change css of AfterShip button?

Tags: css, iframe

I use AfterShip button button and I want to change default css, the service give me an iframe, could I change these css settings?

Here you can see the default view of button
https://www.aftership.com/features/track-button

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

You can't manipulate an iframe. If I were in your position and changing the button style were a must, I would "cheat" my way into position an html box with the style you want above the iframe button (hidding it). Then you could add `pointer-events:none`to your element so the iframe button below would be clickable .

here you have an example with your iframe:

```css
#as-container-150399376720884 {
  position:relative;
}
.myButton {
  height:48px;
  width:126px;
  background-color:red;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:48px;
  pointer-events:none;
  position:absolute;
  left: 375px;
  top: 0px;  
}
```

```html
<div id="as-container-150399376720884" style="width: 100%; height: 64px;">
  <iframe id="as-150399376720884" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://button.aftership.com/button_widget.html?&amp;size=large&amp;id=150399376720884&amp;slug=&amp;width=500px&amp;hide_tracking_number=false&amp;tracking_number=&amp;responsive=true&amp;origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.aftership.com%2Ffeatures%2Ftrack-button&amp;domain=track.aftership.com"
  style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; border: 0px; max-width: 500px; height: 64px;"></iframe>
  <div class="myButton">MY button</div>
</div>
```